# How to use Google business without showing address

Tags: google, local-seo

I'm working on a website and my understanding is, by having the place of business listed with Google Business, it will help with local searches.

The problem we have is, this person is a self employed lady and her business is also her home address, and she doesn't want to provide this location to the world.

Her website shows the town where she lives which appears to be enough for visitors looking for her location, and only after an enquiry is made does she provide her location. The point is, the website does not expose this.

Is it possible to utilise the localisation for searches (Google Business) without it exposing the full address?

Comment: This is a really good question. For one thing I do, we have antique sales events every few weeks where plenty of signs are put out all along the route and the directions are extremely clear, but I hesitate to put a full address on the website for security reasons. After all, this is my Mothers house. I do not want people robbing her when we are not open. And still, there is no good answer for my scenario.

Answer (score 4):

*New Google Business Customers*

When signing up to Google Business click:

- `I deliver goods and services to my customers at their location`

This will inform Google that the customer serves the services at the customers address and ultimately will hide the address.

*Existing Google Business Customers*

If you have already signed up to Google Business then its simply a matter of login and doing the following steps:

1. Click the Edit Pencil under the section address
2. Click I deliver goods and services to my customers at their location
3. If checked then uncheck I also serve customers at my business address

Screenshot

[image: Google Business Unchecked]

*Local SEO without a local Address visible*

You can hide the address on Google and it can still rank but you are still subject to Google's local ranking algorithm, which a major factor is trust and this is linked to having your business address mentioned on various 3rd party websites such as Yelp, Yell, BT, HotFrog etc.

Hiding the address completely on Google, Website and 3rd partys will have a negative impact and will make it much harder to increase those rankings. This is because serious businesses regardless if they are small, big or one-man employeed businesses they should have a visible address for customers to write complaints to, or report for fraudulent activities. After-all, as a consumer do you really want to hand over your hard earned cash to someone that has no address...

Google, and customers don't agree with the 'I don't want my address online' excuse, because if your a business you should have a mailing address at least. Some sole traders like plumbers will use their accountants address for mail.

Some people and businesses will add citations to various sources with `Subject to appointment only` statments. I use this for my own [business on HotFrog](http://www.hotfrog.co.uk/business/dorset/bournemouth/bybe) for example, I seriously recommend that you list your business address on both the website and various reputable sites online.