# Google my business and using only London as an address

Tags: google, local-seo, google-my-business, address

Will Google reprimand me for using London as my address instead of a complete correct address?   I see [a business that seems to do so in an organic search result](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Protilers+Ltd+-+Professional+tilers+in+London./@51.4891189,-0.107706,9z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xb33ac46b12493782!8m2!3d51.4891189!4d-0.107706).

Now what happens is when a person puts in a search for professional tilers this is the result, thus I feel they have cheated the SEO due to the Google My Business listing them only as London as an address, is this something we can all all use, or is this something Google will penalize them for in the future?

Ionna

Answer (score 2):

> [SOURCE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/89208/20604)
>
> Local SEO without a local Address visible
>
> You can hide the address on Google and it can still rank but you are
>   still subject to Google's local ranking algorithm, which a major
>   factor is trust and this is linked to having your business address
>   mentioned on various 3rd party websites such as Yelp, Yell, BT,
>   HotFrog etc.
>
> Hiding the address completely on Google, Website and 3rd partys will
>   have a negative impact and will make it much harder to increase those
>   rankings. This is because serious businesses regardless if they are
>   small, big or one-man employed businesses they should have a visible
>   address for customers to write complaints to, or report for fraudulent
>   activities. After-all, as a consumer do you really want to hand over
>   your hard earned cash to someone that has no address...
>
> Google, and customers don't agree with the 'I don't want my address
>   online' excuse, because if your a business you should have a mailing
>   address at least. Some sole traders like plumbers will use their
>   accountants address for mail.
>
> Some people and businesses will add citations to various sources with
>   Subject to appointment only statements. I use this for my own business
>   on HotFrog for example, I seriously recommend that you list your
>   business address on both the website and various reputable sites
>   online.

So...

Businesses that have physical registered and visible addresses are more trusted by customers and this echoed into the virtual world. Both Google and Bing rewards site for visible (NAP).

If you want search engines rewarding you fully, in the region that you are targetting then you must have a local, visible physical address in that region, or at least visible address on 3rd party websites for NAP.

Also, if your address is registered on the out skirts of London, even if its not visible to customers and you select a radius of 100 miles, then the likelihood is that Google will still favour customers nearer to companies nearer to them, even when you have the address hidden! remember, your address is hidden to Customers, not Google, proximity will still apply, increase your local rankings, increases the proximity rating.